# Get certain value of XML using java

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodelist

I have the XML as follows. How can I loop and retrieve values of tag ClientInfo if EServiceId is "ESRVC2" using Java?

```
<EServiceInfo>
    <EServiceId>ESRVC1</EServiceId>
    <Clients>
        <ClientInfo>
            <ClientEntityID>T1511111F</ClientEntityID>
            <ClientEntityType>UEN</ClientEntityType>
        </ClientInfo>
        <ClientInfo>
            <ClientEntityID>190000001W</ClientEntityID>
            <ClientEntityType>UEN</ClientEntityType>
        </ClientInfo>
    </Clients>
</EServiceInfo>
<EServiceInfo>
    <EServiceId>ESRVC2</EServiceId>
    <Clients>
        <ClientInfo>
            <ClientEntityID>T1522222F</ClientEntityID>
            <ClientEntityType>UEN</ClientEntityType>
        </ClientInfo>
        <ClientInfo>
            <ClientEntityID>190000002W</ClientEntityID>
            <ClientEntityType>UEN</ClientEntityType>
        </ClientInfo>
    </Clients>
</EServiceInfo>
```

Comment: share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please find what I tried below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I tried. But looks like it will return all the 4 ClientInfos.

```
NodeList nEserviceInfoList = doc.getElementsByTagName("EServiceInfo");
        for (int i = 0; i < nEserviceInfoList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = nEserviceInfoList.item(i);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element elem = (Element) nNode;
                Node node1 = elem.getElementsByTagName("EServiceId").item(0);
                String nEServiceId = node1.getTextContent();

                System.out.println("EServiceId: " + nEServiceId);

                NodeList nClientList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ClientInfo");

                for (int j = 0; j < nClientList.getLength(); j++) {

                    Node nClientNode = nClientList.item(j);

                    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nClientNode.getNodeName());
                    if (nClientNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element elemClient = (Element) nClientNode;
                        Node node3 = elemClient.getElementsByTagName("ClientEntityID").item(0);
                        String nClientEntityID = node3.getTextContent();

                        Node node4 = elemClient.getElementsByTagName("ClientEntityType").item(0);
                        String nClientEntityType = node4.getTextContent();

                        System.out.println("ClientEntityID: "+ nClientEntityID);
                        System.out.println("ClientEntityType: "+ nClientEntityType);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edit your question and put this code inside your question for easy readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost complete. Only few changes need.

```
NodeList nClientList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ClientInfo");
```

This code need to change. You are referring the direct root tag to iterate `ClientInfo`, so whatever the condition you make, the iteration process continue with all of the ClientInfo tag. Change `doc` to `elem`

```
NodeList nClientList = elem.getElementsByTagName("ClientInfo");
```

Then enclose the rest of the iteration with conditional block.

```
if (nEServiceId.equals("ESRVC2")) {
  //ClientInfo iteration logic
}
```

Here is the full code for these changes.

```
NodeList nEserviceInfoList = doc.getElementsByTagName("EServiceInfo");
for (int i = 0; i < nEserviceInfoList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nNode = nEserviceInfoList.item(i);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element elem = (Element) nNode;
        Node node1 = elem.getElementsByTagName("EServiceId").item(0);
        String nEServiceId = node1.getTextContent();

        NodeList nClientList = elem.getElementsByTagName("ClientInfo");

        if (nEServiceId.equals("ESRVC2")) {
            System.out.println("EServiceId: " + nEServiceId);
            for (int j = 0; j < nClientList.getLength(); j++) {

                Node nClientNode = nClientList.item(j);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nClientNode.getNodeName());
                if (nClientNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element elemClient = (Element) nClientNode;
                    Node node3 = elemClient.getElementsByTagName("ClientEntityID").item(0);
                    String nClientEntityID = node3.getTextContent();

                    Node node4 = elemClient.getElementsByTagName("ClientEntityType").item(0);
                    String nClientEntityType = node4.getTextContent();

                    System.out.println("ClientEntityID: " + nClientEntityID);
                    System.out.println("ClientEntityType: " + nClientEntityType);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```